# Google sheet Offset 4th parameter

Tags: google-sheets, range, offset

In Excel I am able to use like so:

```
OFFSET(RangeName, 0,0,,1)
```

this will get all values of Column 0 (first column) in my multi-column range.

But when i try to do this in Google Sheet, error comes up:

> Function OFFSET parameter 4 value is 0. It should be greater than or
>   equal to 1.

Parameter 4 is height of range from documentation. How can I get height of range 
"RangeName" to be input to here?

**EDIT**: More info.

RangeName is dynamic. It points to contents of a cell which I can change.
I tried

```
OFFSET(RangeName,0,0,1,1)
```

It works, but the list is cut short to 1 item (obviously).

Comment: The selected range is actually dynamic. so the total item is different everytime. thus i cannot use 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES! I found it! Here is how to do this:

```
OFFSET(RangeName,0,0,COUNTA(RangeName),1)
```

The function COUNTA will return number of items in the range.